# Generate anagrams and write them to a file

Tags: java

This is the code I've written that'll take a word as input and write all its anagrams to a file. The java compiler forces me to use try-catch statements every time I wish to do something with the file. I want to know if there's any way to make my code shorter and more readable in general. As you can see, inside the `write_anagram` function, where I want want to swap two indices `i` and `j`. The code's been long with so many instances of `substring` and `charAt` function. I want to use it for my school project so want it more readable for an examiner. Any improvements I can make? Is there any substitute for `FileWriter` so that I don't have to use try catch many times?

```
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Anagrams
{
    int count;
    FileWriter f;
    
    void write(String s)
    {
        try
        {
            f.write(s+"\n");
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println("An error ocurred while writing to the file");
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
    
    void write_anagrams(String s, int start)
    {
        int i, j;
        String n;
        for(i=start; i<s.length(); i++)
        {
            for(j=i+1; j<s.length(); j++)
            {
                n = s.substring(0,i)+s.charAt(j)+s.substring(i+1, j)+s.charAt(i)+s.substring(j+1);
                write(n);
                count++;
                write_anagrams(n, i+1);
            }
        }
    }
    
    void write_anagrams(String s)
    {
        try
        {
            f = new FileWriter("AnagramsByJava.txt");
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println("An error ocurred while opening the file");
        }
        count = 1;
        write(s);
        write_anagrams(s, 0);
        try
        {
            f.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println("An error ocurred while closing the file");
        }
        System.out.println(count+" anagrams have been written to AnagramsByJava.txt");
    }
    
    public static void main()
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        Anagrams object = new Anagrams();
        System.out.print("Enter a word: ");
        String s = sc.next();
        object.write_anagrams(s);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

*(I'm a little nervous about answering since you mention this is for an exam, but then again we're here to help you learn and it's up to you and your examiners to see that you do the right thing with any help you get.)*

Since you asked about the exceptions, the answer is that if you plan to just crash on exception, then just don't `catch` it and use `throws` instead. Catch it somewhere else, such as in `main`, if you want to display something in particular. But even that's optional - you can even just throw from `main`.

You also should be using `close()` on your resources. You can use the "try-with-resources" pattern to do this for you. In my example, I use `try` only for this purpose - I'm still not `catch`ing anything.

You should free up your anagram logic from knowing that it will be written to a file - if it just gets a `Writer` it can handle the case if we decide we want it written to a file, to the screen, to the internet, to a `String`, or anywhere else.

Then just some minor fancy stuff to give you inspiration re: readability. Google anything you aren't familiar with (`StringBuilder`, `BufferedWriter`, `System.out.format`).

I didn't touch your core anagram logic, though I did put it over several lines in an attempt to make it readable. To be honest it still confuses me how it works, but it does seem to work at least...!

```java
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Anagrams_mine {

    private static int write_anagrams(Writer f, String s, int start, int count)
            throws IOException {
        for (int i = start; i < s.length(); i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < s.length(); j++) {
                String n = new StringBuilder(s.length())
                        .append(s.substring(0, i))
                        .append(s.charAt(j))
                        .append(s.substring(i + 1, j))
                        .append(s.charAt(i))
                        .append(s.substring(j + 1))
                        .toString();
                f.write(n + "\n");
                count = write_anagrams(f, n, i + 1, count + 1);
            }
        }
        return count;
    }

    static int write_anagrams(Writer f, String s) throws IOException {
        f.write(s + "\n");
        return write_anagrams(f, s, 0, 1);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
                Writer f = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("AnagramsByJava.txt"))) {
            System.out.print("Enter a word: ");
            int count = write_anagrams(f, scanner.next());
            f.flush();
            System.out.format("%s anagrams have been written.", count);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this code. Hey this logic is simple. It is based on swapping indices. Say u have a word ABCD... We will swap 0 and 1 index then 0 and 2 index & so on... Now each of the swapped say BACD is swapped further from 1 index, i. e, we swap 1 and 2 index, 1 and 3 so on... So it goes on in a recursion until we've got all anagrams...!!